# How to delete <0xfeff> characters in Delta table?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have some BOM characters in my Delta tables.
Environment :  Databricks - Microsoft Azure.

I would like to find these characters <0xfeff> and delete it. But I don't know how to do it.

I tried to catch these characters during the ingestion and delete them with Pyspark.

Do you have an idea to do it directly with SQL perhaps ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and what you have tried?

Comment: When I open the csv file in SublimeText, I have this <0xfeff> in front of some string.

Comment: Please provide example of your data. Maybe you have a dataframe? The result of `df.printSchema()` and `df.show()` could help.